# List of LOOP keywords

Tags: loops, common-lisp

Is there anywhere, a list of the keywords that can introduce a new clause in the LOOP macro? http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/m_loop.htm is informative, but I'm still not clear about which words in the provided grammar are literal keywords as opposed to production names, and whether there are some keywords that can only occur within a clause, as opposed to introducing a new clause.

Comment: http://clqr.boundp.org/download.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here they are. These can introduce a clause:

**Name Clause**

```
named
```

**Variable Clauses**

```
initially finally for as with
```

**Main Clauses**

```
do collect collecting append
appending nconc nconcing into count
counting sum summing maximize return
maximizing minimize minimizing doing 
thereis always never if when
unless repeat while until
```

These don’t introduce clauses

```
= and it else end from upfrom 
above below to upto downto downfrom 
in on then across being each the hash-key
hash-keys of using hash-value hash-values
symbol symbols present-symbol 
present-symbols external-symbol 
external-symbols fixnum float t nil of-type
```

But note that it’s the parsing that determines what is a keyword. For example in:

```
(loop for key in hash-values)
```

Only `for` and `in` are keywords.